# Is std::swap specialized in Eigen

Tags: eigen

I found in documentation that `matrix.swap(other)` is defined in Eigen.

Is `std::swap(matrix, other)` specialized using the swap method?

I'm asking this because if not, I'd like to specialized it myself.

Comment: what speaks against using ```std::swap``` on pointers to Eigen Matrixes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::swap` does not work on Eigen's objects and it cannot really be specialised because `std::swap` has only one template parameter. Both arguments must be of the same type.

You can still implement your own `swap` free function in your own namespace. See for instance this [discussion](http://listengine.tuxfamily.org/lists.tuxfamily.org/eigen/2010/04/msg00020.html).